# Breeze/Knockout dropdown causing entity to be modified

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, breeze

This is a bit of an odd issue I came across today. I have an application that is using Breeze and Knockout. On one of my pages I allow the user to edit and save project data. The save button is only enabled if a change has been made. To track changes I subscribe to the propertyChanged event. This page has quite a few dropdowns which are causing some problems. Here is an example of one of the dropdowns.

```
<div>
    <label for="projQAManager">QA Manager</label>
    <select id="projQAManager" data-bind="options: QAManagers,
                                          optionsText: 'FullName',
                                          optionsValue: 'USERNAME',
                                          optionsCaption: 'None',
                                          value: project().QAManager"></select>
</div>
```

The issue occurs when project().QAManager is "". The propertyChanged event gets fired as soon as the project is loaded and it shows the QAManager field being changed from "" to null. This is causing the entity to believe it has been modified even though nothing has really changed. If QAManager is already null everything works fine. I suppose I could go through and try and clean the DB and clear out any fields with "" and set them to null if I had to but I would rather not if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies indeed with the fact that KnockoutJS assigns the value `undefined` to the caption of the list box, which you labelled "None".

What happens is that right after the listbox is populated, KnockoutJS checks if your selected value (`project().QAManager`) matches any of the options listed in the list box. If it does not match, it selects the option with the caption, and as such, the selected value of the listbox is modified, which triggers `project().QAManager` to get the `undefined` value.

Excerpt from the documentation of the `options` binding handler (emphasis is mine):

> KO will prefix the list of items with one that displays the text
>   [caption text] and has the value **undefined**. So, if myChosenValue
>   holds the value undefined (which observables do by default), then the
>   dummy option will be selected. **If the optionsCaption parameter is an
>   observable, then the text of the initial item will update as the
>   observable’s value changes**.

I thought of the following workarounds ranging from the easiest to the hardest, but most "proper":

1. One of the workaround would be to add to your list of options (`QAManagers`) an entry which has the value undefined, before it is available as an observable array.
2. Write a custom binding handler for options that allows to set a given value to the caption item, instead of it being set to `undefined`. This should consist in copy/pasting 99% of KnockoutJS's implementation of "options", and just changing the code I wrote at option 3.
3. Change KnockoutJS's source so that a new "optionsCaptionValue" binding is taken into account, like this (I've modified the original code like you should do):

   ```
       if (allBindings['optionsCaption']) {
           var option = document.createElement("option");
           ko.utils.setHtml(option, allBindings['optionsCaption']);

           var captionsValue;
           if (allBindings['optionsCaptionValue']) {
              captionsValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings['optionsCaptionValue']);
           }
           ko.selectExtensions.writeValue(option, captionsValue ? captionsValue : undefined);
           element.appendChild(option);
       }
   ```